# Programming logical operations as arguments using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyeval

How do I feed logical arguments to functions in R, programming with tidyverse functions? [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679872/programming-a-filter-in-tidyverse-using-quoting) does not allow the user to change the logical operator, it assumes the user of the function always wants `==`.

See code below for example and attempts so far.

```
# example data
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(x = letters[1:4], y = 1:4, z = 5:8)

# what I want to do is have a function that passes arguments to filter()
# so that I can flexibly subset data:
dat %>% 
  filter(x == "a" | y < 2)

dat %>% 
  filter(x == "b" & y < 1)

dat %>% 
  filter(y == max(y))

# what would I pass to lgl to do this in a function?
# I want to be a ble to feed in different logical expressions, notalways using
#    the same variables and operations, like the documentation for filter()
#    demonstrates

# tries so far:
fun <- function(dat, lgl) filter(dat, lgl)
fun(dat, x == "a" | y < 2)

fun <- function(dat, lgl) filter(dat, quo(lgl))
fun(dat, x == "a" | y < 2)

fun <- function(dat, lgl) filter(dat, quos(lgl))
fun(dat, x == "a" | y < 2)

fun <- function(dat, lgl) filter(dat, !!sym(lgl))
fun(dat, 'x == "a" | y < 2')

fun <- function(dat, lgl) filter(dat, !!!syms(lgl))
fun(dat, 'x == "a" | y < 2')

fun <- function(dat, lgl) filter(dat, expr(lgl))
fun(dat, x == "a" | y < 2)

fun <- function(dat, lgl) filter(dat, eval(lgl, envir = parent.frame()))
fun(dat, x == "a" | y < 2)
```

Comment: Why not use `filter(dat, x == "a" | y <2)`? Is there another use case that you could describe that won't allow that?

Comment: This is only a minimally reproducible example. The function itself does a whole host of data wrangling and summarizing. The filter bit is the only place where I was hung up, though. And I wanted a function instead of copy-pasting the stanza of code an inordinate amount of times.

Comment: Well, in that case, I'm not aware of any way to pass in column names appropriately (aside from your solution below), but you can do something like this `fun <- function(dat, lgl, ...) filter(dat, eval(lgl)); fun(dat, expression(x = 5 | y <2))`. I don't recommend passing the expression as a string, if only because parsing is rather messy, so you have to use things like `xor` instead of `|`, which I've never figured out how to escape appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I as writing the example out, I found the solution. But I thought I would post here just in case anyone ran into a similar issue:

```
> fun <- function(dat, ...) filter(dat, ...)
> fun(dat, x == "a" | y < 2)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  x         y     z
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 a         1     5
```

It is somewhat of a workaround, though, as it in't actually interpreting the expression, but just passing the argument along. Would be interesting to see another solution, as well.